# Azure Vitual machine deployment

Tags: azure

Azure resource manager power shell or JSON template to create Virtual machine in existing Virtual network and Storage account.

Comment: What's you question?

Comment: Add more information..

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use either. 
Json Template is basically what [Azure Resource Manager (ARM)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/) uses anway. Bonus: you can run your ARM templates from PowerShell :)

The question you want to ask is:

Will I be doing this repeatedly?

If so, ARM is the natural answer. You create a resource in a file that you can version control and use to repeated deployments.

If it's only a one-time thing, then [PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/) or [Azure Command Line Tools](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-command-line-tools/) are more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

At first steps JSON templates may confuse you, because files are large (hundreds of lines). But templates are really readable and you can easy configure your architecture. Also there is a chance to make a syntax mistake or to violate existing restrictions - try to use smart editor. 
For example, [VS Code Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msazurermtools.azurerm-vscode-tools).

PowerShell and multi-platform tool Azure CLI help you make the same requests to subscriptions but contain helpers, hints and validators which would help you easy set correct options.